# Flex-wrap wrapping twice when it can only wrap once

Tags: html, css, flexbox

So, I have some text and a moving cursor. I want that cursor to move to the next line when it hits the edge of the screen. With the code below, the cursor is moving to it's own line with *flex-wrap: wrap*.That seems fine if ***only** the cursor touches the edge. Though, when another word of the text is on a new line because of *overflow-wrap: break-word* the cursor goes to its own line? How would I go about fixing this so that the cursor stays with the word as much as possible?

Pictures:
[Cursor not wrapping because it fits on the line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X2Kbf.png)
[Cursor wrapping because it doesn't fit on the screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rw7RU.png)
[Okay, what happened?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrPpM.png)

```css
.typing-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

#start-line {
  color: white;
  margin: 0px 5px;
  font-size: 1.9rem;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#cursor {
  margin-top: 5px;
  background-color: #FFF;
  height: 1.9rem;
  width: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="typing-content">
  <p id="start-line">AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH </p>
  <div id="cursor"></div>
</div>
```

I was expecting the cursor to not be on it's own line, when it clearly has enough room on the line where view is. I tried many things such has changing the *flex-wrap* or not even giving it wrapping, but none of those worked.

Comment: Put your cursor element inside your paragraph and turn it into an inline element like span instead of a div

Comment: Wow, that worked! Need to read up on different display types for elements. If you want to, you can post this comment as a answer, and I'll mark it as the solution!

All I did different or wasn't stated was: make the cursor display as _inline-block_ and used relative positioning.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explained**

when you wrap the text inside an element, the space reserved for that element calculated by the widest line. This is probably because most html elements have a rectangular form. Even if you adjust the width of both elements to fit on the same row still the wrapped text into your paragraph is displayed on multiple lines. This results your curser element to be displayed apart from the last letter of you r paragraph instead of sticking to it.

**Solution**

Moving your cursor element into the paragraph element and turning it into a span element (will be explained below) and set display to inline-block to keep it's width height considered, this allows html to consider this element as part of the paragraph container while wrapping the content.

Css code

```
#cursor {
    margin-top: 5px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    height: 1.9rem;
    width: 1rem;
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Your html code

```
    <div class="typing-content">
          <p id="start-line">AHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHHH 
               <span id="cursor"></span>
          </p>
        </div>
```

**Important**

When your cursor element is inside the paragraph you need to turn it into an element like span that does not automatically close the paragraph element tag and therefore jump out and being considered as a sibling element. This is because of the [tag omission](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p#:%7E:text=The%20HTML%20element%20represents,as%20images%20or%20form%20fields.) in paragraph element.

[Stackblitz example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/web-platform-sp6843?file=index.html)